# Persistance of OpenMP thread teams across functions

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I have a simple program that I am using for physics simulation. I want to know how to implement a certain threading paradigm in OpenMP.

```
int main()
{
#define steps (100000)
   for (int t = 0;t < steps; t++)
   {
     firstParallelLoop();
     secondParallelLoop();
     if (!(t%100))
     {
        checkpoint();
     }
   }
}
void firstParallelLoop()
{// In another file.c
  #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfSim;i++)
   {
     //Some atomic floating point ops.
   }
}
```

Formerly, I was using pthreads and got a 1.7 speedup on my dualcore laptop. I can't seem to get any speedup when using OpenMP. I suspect the problem is that the thread groups/pools are rapidly being created and destroyed with disasterous effect.

In my pthreads implementations I needed to ensure that no new threads were created, and that my program behaved as a client-server. In the pthreads scheme, the main() was a server and calls to firstParallelLoop would release mutexes/semaphores that triggered the thread to reprocess the data.

When I look at CPU utilization I expect it to be over the 30% mark (4 core, 2 are HT), but it stays around 27...

How do I get OpenMP to do something similar? How can I tell OpenMP to reuse my threads?

Comment: Do you have the right compiler options enabled? Most implementations of OpenMP will indeed pool threads.

Comment: If your CPU usage isn't increasing, then you probably never enabled OpenMP. What are your compilation options? How big is `sizeOfSim`?

Comment: sizeOfSim is a 10,000 by 10,000 grid where the neighbors are averaged and scaled (FDTD). I guess what I want is to figure out is how can I debug what OpenMP is doing? Can I force OpenMP to pool threads?

Comment: So what compiler options are you using? I still suspect that you never enabled OpenMP.

Comment: -ffast-math -mtune=corei7 -march=corei7 -fopenmp for gcc and -lmgl -lgomp for ldd

Comment: hmm... Then I can't see anything wrong. Can you provide a working SSCCE that shows the non-speedup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GCC OpenMP run-time `libgomp` implements thread teams on POSIX systems by something akin to a thread pool - threads are only created when the first parallel region is encountered, with each thread running an infinite work loop. Entering and exiting a parallel region is implemented with barriers. By default `libgomp` uses a combination of busy-waiting and sleeping to implement barriers. The amount of busy-waiting is controlled by the `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` environment variable. If it is not specified, threads that wait on a barrier would busy-wait for 300000 spins (3 ms at 100000 spins/msec) and then would go into sleeping state. If `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` is set to `active`, then the busy-wait time is increased to 30000000000 spins (5 mins at 100000 spins/sec). You can fine tune the busy-waiting time by setting the `GOMP_SPINCOUNT` variable to the number of busy cycles (`libgomp` assumes about 100000 spins/msec but it could vary by a factor of 5 depending on the CPU). You can fully disable sleeping like this:

```
OMP_WAIT_POLICY=active GOMP_SPINCOUNT=infinite OMP_NUM_THREADS=... ./program
```

This would somehow improve the thread team starting time, but at the expense of CPU time as idle threads would not idle but rather busy-wait.

In order to remove the overhead you should rewrite your program in more OpenMP-friendly way. Your example code could be rewritten like this:

```
int main()
{
#define steps (100000)
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      for (int t = 0; t < steps; t++)
      {
         firstParallelLoop();
         secondParallelLoop();
         if (!(t%100))
         {
            #pragma omp master
            checkpoint();
            #pragma omp barrier
         }
      }
   }
}
void firstParallelLoop()
{// In another file.c
   #pragma omp for
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfSim; i++)
   {
      //Some atomic floating point ops.
   }
}
```

Note the following two things:

- A parallel region is inserted in the main program. It is **not** a `parallel for` though. All threads in the team would execute the outer loop `steps` times.
- The `for` loop in `firstParallelLoop` is made parallel by using `omp for` only. Thus it will execute as a serial loop if called outside an OpenMP parallel and as parallel when called from inside a parallel region. The same should be done for the loop in `secondParallelLoop`.

The barrier in the main loop is used to ensure that other threads would wait for the checkpoint to finish before starting the next iteration.