# How to statistically measure OpenMP performance within a program?

Tags: openmp

I want to statistically measure performance of a program that I have parallelized with OpenMP. I opted for writing a loop within a testing application that executes the parallel algorithm `MAX_EXPERIMENTS` times and reports the time measurements into a file.

The problem solution seems to be more complex than extracting the parallel pragma above the outer loop, as I have serial parts of the code inbetween inner parallel loops.

The code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector> 
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX_NUMBERS = 1e07; 
    const int MAX_EXPERIMENTS = 1e02; 

    std::random_device rd;  
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
    std::bernoulli_distribution dis(0.1);

    vector<double> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(MAX_NUMBERS); 

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; ++i)
    {
        if (dis(gen))
            numbers.emplace_back(100); 
        else 
            numbers.emplace_back(1);
    }

    stringstream ss; 
    ss << "time-measurements-nthread-" << setfill('0') << setw(2) 
        << omp_get_max_threads() << ".csv"; 

    ofstream exp(ss.str()); 
    exp << "time\n"; 

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MAX_EXPERIMENTS; ++i)
    {
        // BEGIN: Tested parallel program
        double t0 = omp_get_wtime();  

        // Some serial work.

        double x = 0; 
        //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:x)  // exp-01
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:x)  // exp-02
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) 
        {
            if (numbers[i] > 1)
               x = x + cos(numbers[i]); // Some work being done.
        }
        double t1 = omp_get_wtime(); 

        // Some serial work

        // Measure program execution
        exp << t1 - t0 << "\n";

        // END: Tested parallel program
    }

};
```

The program first serially initializes `1e07` numbers to either `1` or `100` such that the probability of hitting `100` is `10%`, which matches my real world input data.

The main testing loop performs `100` experiments, and the loop body models theh tested parallel algorithm. There are parts of the parallel algorithm that must be executed in serial. Writing `pragma omp parallel for` within a loop is supposed to be a bad idea, as it will open and close threads each time an experiment is being created.

**Question 1**: even though usually one would avoid opening parallel regions within loops, is this justified in this case, where each experimental loop step represents an independent parallel program execution, and the preparation of input data for the experiment is much faster at runtime?

To visualize the written data, I've used python (jupyter nootebook code):

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import os

rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10,20]
rcParams["font.size"] = 24 

def plot_experiment(expattern):
    thread1df = pd.read_csv("time-measurements-nthread-01-%s.csv" % expattern)
    thread2df = pd.read_csv("time-measurements-nthread-02-%s.csv" % expattern)
    thread4df = pd.read_csv("time-measurements-nthread-04-%s.csv" % expattern)
    thread8df = pd.read_csv("time-measurements-nthread-08-%s.csv" % expattern)


    f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

    ax1.plot(thread1df["time"], label="time 1", color='g')
    ax1.plot(thread2df["time"], label="time 2", color='r')
    ax1.plot(thread4df["time"], label="time 4", color='b')
    ax1.plot(thread8df["time"], label="time 8", color='k')

    ax2.plot(thread1df["time"] / thread8df["time"], label="speedup 8", color='k')
    ax2.plot(thread1df["time"] / thread4df["time"], label="speedup 4", color='b')
    ax2.plot(thread1df["time"] / thread2df["time"], label="speedup 2", color='r')

    ax1.set_ylabel("Time in seconds")
    ax1.legend()

    ax2.set_xlabel("Test number")
    ax2.legend()
    ax2.set_ylabel("Speedup")


plot_experiment("exp-01")
```

And the application is compiled with gcc, using optimization: `g++ -std=c++1y -fopenmp -O3  main.cpp -o main`

The experiment is executed with `for i in 1 2 4 8; do export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$i && ./main && sleep 5; done;`

And the experiment files are then re-named for pandas using `for file in *nthread-0[0-9].csv*; do mv $file ${file/.csv/-exp-02.csv}; done` (replace `exp-02` with `exp-01` for the first experiment).

In the first experiment, I've tried dynamic scheduling and got the following diagrams:

[image]

And that's weird because it seems that adding threads slows down the program. Checking the bottlenecks with [HPCToolkit](http://hpctoolkit.org/) for `exp-01` and `8` threads, I've noticed that OpenMP spends a ton of time in switching in the `dynamic` scheduling mode:

[image]

So I switched the scheduling mode to `static` and re-ran the experiments, then got the following:

[image]

Now there is some scaling there, at least for `2` threads, but now `4` threads are oscillating too much and there is not much effect in using `8` threads. I checked it using `HPCToolkit` again and got this:

[image]

I *think* this is telling me that starting and stopping threads is eating up `85%` of my runtime with `8` threads, however the HPCToolkit manual states

> Furthermore, if the filtered nodes are children of a “fake” procedures
>   (such as program_root and thread_root), the exclusive metrics in
>   callers view and flat view can be misleading.

**Question 2**: Does the experiment 02 have a significant overhead in opening and closing the parallel region within the experiment loop? If so, how to go around this, taking into account the serial parts of the algorithm?

Software: Arch Linux, g++ (GCC) 7.1.1 20170630, hpcrun: A member of HPCToolkit, version 2017.11, CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz

**Edit**

I have tried changing the thread persistency behavior using the environmental variables as proposed [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614835/persistance-of-openmp-thread-teams-across-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
export OMP_WAIT_POLICY=active GOMP_SPINCOUNT=infinite
```

here are the results:

[image]

Obviously, the oscillations caused by the thread creation / destruction are much lower, but are they gone? Is there a way to change the program so that I don't have to rely on spinning threads? Investigating bottlenecks of this program will still show substantial amount of CPU cycles being spent by spinning threads.

Comment: Thank you for describing your question so precisely! Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/12614835/620382 - it doesn't immediately look like it, but I think it is fundamentally similar and Hristo Iliev's excellent answer should address both your questions. If you have any aspects not covered there, please clarify.

Comment: @Zulan: thanks! I've read about the environmental variables in the "next step" OpenMP book, but this seems to be a workaround for this test. I can't really extract the parallel pragma to the experimental loop, because I have serial code that needs to do its work above and below the parallel loop.  I'm recoding the test application so that it will be called MAX_EXPERIMENTS times, but it is taking substantially longer, as each time I  call the test now, I need to read a ton of data from the disk (emulated by the initialization in the model in my question).

Comment: The point is to put the serial parts in a `#pragma omp master` or `#pragma omp single` and keep the remaining threads active in a barrier - ready to go with low latency.

Comment: @Zulan: Thanks. Is this also OK if the second serial part needs to access data from the first one? Can this also work without changing the parallel algorithm just for the sake of measurement?

Comment: As long as you use appropriate barriers - there is already an implicit barrier at the end of a `omp for` worksharing construct - you are fine to access dependent data across serial sections of code. I do not understand what you mean by "changing the parallel algorithm".

Comment: @Zulan: I've been trying to work with the barriers, but the problem seems also to be in the serial parts of the algorithm. I cannot put the first and the second serial algorithm part in a `single` environment without extracting the data they are working on as global data: this is what I mean by changing the algorithm. Instead of having some data initialized and used within the loop, I now have to make it shared between two `single` environments. Thank you for the advice, I will try to make it work this way, and not rely on the enviornmental variables.

Comment: If you need data across different `single` constructs, you can use shared variables declared outside of the parallel scope safely.

Comment: @Zulan: yep, thanks, that is exactly what I am doing. But for this I need to re-arrange the order of variables in the code of course, extract them from the scopes of `single` regions to either the scope of the exp. loop or the global program scope. That's what I meant by changing the alg. The data I am using in the real code is really complex: unstructured meshes (volumes and surfaces), octrees, addressing lists, etc, so I wanted to avoid re-organizing the code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion in the comments it seem that your main problem is that you have a complex existing application and want to place a workshared loop in some inner part. But creating all threads only there is too much overhead in your application, thread pooling by libgomp seems insufficient.

If you want to do this without restructuring, it might help to use `taskloop`, which works similar to `for`, but can be nested within a `single` portion. In turn it may not be as efficient as `for. Essentially your code would look like this:

```
int a;
#pragma omp parallel
{
  int b;
  #pragma omp single
  {
    int c;
    // lots of serial code
    // somewhere inbetween
    #pragma omp taskloop
    for (...) {
      int d;
    }
    // lots of serial code
  }
}
```

Note that data-sharing for task generation constructs works a bit differently. By default a variable declared outside of the parallel region (`a`) is `shared` within the `parallel` region and also shared among the tasks executing the inner loop. A variable declared inside the parallel region, but outside the `taskloop` (`b`,`c`), is `private` within the parallel region and `firstprivate` - that is each thread has it's own copy that is initialized with the outer value. Finally `d` is just local to each loop iteration.

Edit: Do not put any barriers in. Due to implicit taskgroup, the serial portion and the tasks are isolated in their execution.